# (C++) Getting inconsistent results while using Nodes/Linked Lists.

Tags: c++, list, hyperlink, append, head

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

void append(Node*&, int);
void printList(Node*);
void insertNode(Node*&, int, int);
void searchList(Node*, int, int);
int main()
{
    Node* head = nullptr;

    int initialCount = -1, userInput, newNodeLoc = -1, newNodeVal, searchVal;

                        /// INITIALIZE LIST
    while(initialCount <= 0)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the number of initial nodes (must be at least 1): ";
        cin>>initialCount;
    }
    cout<<endl;

    for(int i = 0;i<initialCount;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Enter a number: ";
        cin>>userInput;
        append(head,userInput);
    }
    cout<<endl;

    cout<<"Here are the initial values in the linked list: "<<endl;
    printList(head);

    cout<<"\nEnter a number for a new node to insert to the linked list: ";
    cin>>newNodeVal;
    cout<<endl;
    cout<<"Enter which position you want to insert it (ex. "<<head->data<<" is at pos 1): ";
    cin>>newNodeLoc;
    while((newNodeLoc<=0 || newNodeLoc>initialCount))
    {
        cout<<"New position must be greater than 1 and less than " << initialCount+1 <<": ";
        cin>>newNodeLoc;
    }
    newNodeLoc--;
    insertNode(head, newNodeVal, newNodeLoc);

    cout<<"\nHere is the updated linked list: "<<endl;
    printList(head);

                        /// SEARCH
    cout<<"\nEnter the number that you want to search for in the list: ";
    cin>>searchVal;
    cout<<endl;

    initialCount++;
    cout<<initialCount;
    searchList(head,searchVal,initialCount);

    return 0;
}
void printList(Node* head)
{
    Node *n = head;
    cout<<n->data<<endl;
    while(n->next != nullptr)   // print out all nodes values'
    {
        cout << n->next->data<<endl;
        n = n->next;
    }
}
void append(Node*& head, int val)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    temp->data = val;
    temp->next = nullptr;

    Node* ptr = head;

    if(head == nullptr)                 // check if list is empty
    {
        head = temp;
    }
    else
    {
        while(ptr->next != nullptr)     // if list isn't empty, get to last element set it equal to temp
        {
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        if(ptr->next == nullptr)
        {
            ptr->next = temp;
        }
    }

    delete temp;
    temp = nullptr;

}
void insertNode(Node*& head, int val, int loc)
{
    Node* temp = new Node;
    Node* prevLoc = new Node;
    Node* curr = head;


    temp->data = val;

    int tempPos = 0;

    while(curr->next != nullptr && tempPos != loc)
    {
        prevLoc = curr;
        curr = curr->next;
        tempPos++;
    }

    prevLoc->next = temp;
    temp->next = curr;

    delete temp;
    delete prevLoc;
    curr = nullptr;
    prevLoc = nullptr;
}
void searchList(Node* head, int sVal, int iCount)
{
    Node* curr = head;
    int index=0;

    while(curr->next != nullptr && curr->next->data != sVal)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
        index++;
    }

    cout<<index;
    cout<<iCount;
    if(index != iCount)
    {
        cout<<"Number found at index "<<index<<" in the linked list!";
    }
    if(index-1 == iCount)
        cout<<"Number could not be found in this linked list.";

    delete curr;
    curr = nullptr;

}
```

Hi there! I'm trying to implement append/prntlist/insertnode/search functions and I'm getting extremely inconsistent compiling results. Sometimes the code will run fine. Sometimes the code will randomly break. Other times it'll print out numbers on an infinite loop. I'm thinking it's a memory leak somewhere (in append/print functions), but I'm not super confident. It might also be a loop that's breaking the code. Any and all help is appreciated! **I understand that the search function doesn't work so you can ignore it.** Thank you!

Comment: Did you try running this in a debugger ?  What did you learn from that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `append()`:

```
delete temp;
```

`temp` is your new element, that you've just `append`()ed to the list. Now that it's a part of the list, it gets immediately `delete`d. Good-bye!

The next to the last element of your linked list now points to deleted memory. Subsequent attempt to walk the list results in undefined behavior. Subsequent attempts to append more elements to the list will just make things even worse, scribbling over `delete`ed memory (if it wasn't scribbled over anyway, by the next `new`) and generally making a major mess of everything.

The memory allocation logic in `insert`() is similarly flawed. It's even worse. Two `new`s and two `delete`s. Furthermore, the overall logic is also wrong. Its ostensible purpose is to insert one more element to the list, so it shouldn't be allocating two new nodes, only one will do. Both append() and insert() add one more node to the list; so only one node needs to be `new`ed in both cases.

But the overall problem is erroneous deletions of `new`ed elements, when they should not be `new`ed, and they continue to be used. You cannot use anything after it gets `delete`d. It's gone. It ceased to exist. It joined the choir-invisible. It's an ex-object. But the shown code erroneously `delete`s an element after it gets added to the link list and, ostensibly, is still logically a part of the link list.